# Why is not returning the JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude from google maps API, I'm also using a PHP RESTful API that I've been developing, but I can not get/print the array with the values, am I doing correctly?

I've already tried it using the postman app, to see if I'm getting something, but it gave the 200 status and it doesn´t show anything. This is the way i'm doing the call:

https://skeleton-app-itson.000webhostapp.com/rest/index.php/Prueba/latLong/Mexico

This is problem

```
function latLong_get($address){
        if(!empty($address)){
            //Formatted address
            $formattedAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
            //Send request and receive json data by address
            $geocodeFromAddr = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddr.'&sensor=false&key=IALREADYHAVETHEKEY'); 
            $output = json_decode($geocodeFromAddr);
            //Get latitude and longitute from json data
            $data['latitude']  = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; 
            $data['longitude'] = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
            //Return latitude and longitude of the given address
            if(!empty($data)){

                 echo $data;

            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;   
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting an array with the values, but I've been getting an empty screen

Comment: Checking to see if `$output` has the value you expect would be a good start.

Comment: Also, the URL you are using seems awfully wrong. It is `https://skeleton-app-itson.000webhostapp.com/rest/index.php/Prueba/latLong/Mexico` and it makes it look like you have a folder called `index.php`. How is that supposed to work? At least you could have something like https://skeleton-app-itson.000webhostapp.com/rest/index.php?place=Prueba&lat=<some-latitude>&long=<some-longitude>&country=Mexico

Answer (score 0):

You try to print an array - this is error. For example, you can try

```
if(!empty($data)){
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```